# c++ UWP - How to open blank page as tab inside MainPage

Tags: c++, uwp

Hope you could help me with something I'm not getting any results on Google. I have my MainPage.xaml which has a button inside a Hamburger menu. When I click this button I want to be able to open BlankPage.xaml inside a SplitView in MainPage.xaml but as a closable tab. The only reference I have is this picture. [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FYvf.jpg)

Note the red circle is what I want to be able to do. And note I am using C++.

Thanx in advance.

[Edit] I decided to go for a StackPanel which contains another StackPanel with 2 buttons. One button to open the tab and another to close is completely.

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="TabPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1450" Height="26" Margin="50 40 0 0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PageTab1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button x:Name="TabNameBtn" Content="Tab1" FontSize="11" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
            <Button x:Name="TabCloseBtn" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10A;" FontWeight="ExtraLight" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Width="26" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

How do I add another "PageTab1" (Incremented as "PageTab2, "PageTab3"...) to "TabPanel" with c++ code when a button is pressed?

Comment: You can use frame inside a pivot
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot

Comment: Thanx. Will get back to you about this as soon as I test it.

Comment: I decided to go for a StackPanel which would be my tab button, which also contains a close button.

Comment: A Pivot would be perfect it only had a close button. What I'm trying to do is like a Microsoft Edge page tab.

Comment: I would point you to the open toolkit item for this, but it requires C#. https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1672 I have some initial work on an extension to add a close button.  You can at least see how it's done.